# Similar Parabolae

Tags: conic-sections

From a geometric standpoint,is there only one "true" parabola like there is only one "true" circle? In the sense,all circles are similar to each other by suitable dilations and translations.How can we infer the same for parabola?

Comment: Relevant video on this very topic by standupmaths on YouTube -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoh4TmPzu1w

Comment: More generally, there is only one conic up to similarity with a given eccentricity $e$ ($e=1$ for parabola, $e=0$ for circle).

Comment: Ah, I get it now.Translate the focus and directrix of the parabola and we are done!Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Similarity_to_the_unit_parabola